# Using Web Setup Project for multiple types of projects

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, installation

I am trying to a create an installer for my web application. My solution contains several projects. They include:

- Class library project (referenced by the web application)
- Web Application
- Windows Service
- Web Services project
- Database project (execute update script)

I also have an unmanaged dll (crystal reports) in my web application project, so I might have to do some editing of the registry.

I ideally want to be able to use a web setup project to install the whole solution. Can this be done? Is there a better method/solution?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "Yes" it can be done.

Other better solution? Well, I'm not a huge fan of VS.NET's installer/setup, can be kind of bulky, 3rd parties could be better at a price. Having said that, it should be able to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: What is your sugestion as the best aprouch to this question?